# Pgfplots gives spurious lines in external mode with geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, geometry, tikz-external

This is not a major problem but all the same I would like to confirm that I am not doing anything wrong. `Geometry` package with `showframe=true` option is used to see if all the figures are within the margins. Also, `tikz external` library is used and the plot shows some spurious horizontal and vertical lines.

[image: wrong plot]

This happens only if `showframe=true` is set in `geometry` and the `tikz` `external` library is used. If `external` is switched off, the plot is drawn correctly. As I said earlier, since I am not going to display frame in the final draft, this is not a major issue.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[showframe=true,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

%Comment out to not use external library and get correct figure.
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the comment of @JLDiaz should become an answer. Apparently, both packages change the TeX `\shipout` routine. As long as the resulting bounding box is correct...

Comment: @JLDiaz Can you convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: @percusse Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those spurious lines are the ones drawn by geometry package to delimit the position of the header and the main body.

Apparently when external mode is used, tikz draws the figure in the upper left corner of the page, and crops it at the appropiate size, but the layout marks are still visible.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and fixed it by writing the following after the `\tikzexternalize` command:

```
\tikzifexternalizing{\setkeys{Gm}{showframe=false}}{}
```