# Unwanted blue line with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

After a figure construction in my thesis, the compiled figure has an unwanted blue line. The figure is within the margins of the page. So I don't understand why does the blue line shows up and don't know how to remove it.

[image: Failed]

When I try to compile the code as a MWE, it works like a charm as follows:

```
 \documentclass{memoir}
 \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \section{First Section}

 \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \node[anchor=south west] (x) at (0,0) {$x(t)$};

         \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0)--(1,0);

         \draw  (1,-1) rectangle (3.5,1);
         \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.25mm]}] (1.2,-0.9)--(1.2,0.9);
         \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.25mm]}] (1.1,-0.8)--(3.4,-0.8);
         \draw (1.2,0.2) -- (2.2,0.2);
         \draw (2.2,0.2) -- (3,-0.8);
         \node[anchor=center] (a) at (2.25,0.7) {AAF};
         \node[anchor=south east] (b) at (3.4,-0.8) {$f$};

         \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (3.5,0)--(5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$x_1(t)$};

         \draw  (5,-0.5) rectangle (6,0.5);
         \draw (5.5, -0.8) circle (0.1) node[anchor=north west] {$f_s$};
         \draw (5.5,-0.7) -- (5.5,-0.5);
         \node[anchor=center] (c) at (5.5,0) {S/H};

         \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (6,0)--(7.5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$y(k)$};

         \draw  (7.5,-1) rectangle (10,1);
         \draw (7.75,-0.9) -| (8.25,-0.5);
         \draw (8.25,-0.5) -| (8.75,0);
         \draw (8.75,0) -| (9.25,0.5);
         \draw (9.25,0.5) -- (9.75,0.5);
         \node[anchor=center] (d) at (8.75,0.75) {Quantizer};

         \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (10,0)--(11.5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$y(k)$};

         \draw  (11.5,-0.5) rectangle (13,0.5);
         \node[anchor=center] (e) at (12.25,0.2) {Binary};
         \node[anchor=center] (f) at (12.25,-0.2) {Encoder};

         \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (13,0)--(14,0) node[anchor=south east] {$z$};
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{Generic scheme for an ADC.}
     \label{fig:generic_adc_scheme}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Correct compilation]

I should add that in my thesis I use external figure compilation:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
```

But it doesn't affect the outcome in the MWE.

**EDIT:**

After JLDiaz's comment, I tried to scale down figure and the blue line desappears indeed. Then I made a new "big" figure, which checked JLDiaz's hypotesis. The problem here is that the externalization compiles the figures on the first page of the document, which in my thesis is the front page, that contains the mysterious blue line.

The solution that I found was to replace the front page with an blank empty page, compile the document (which compiles the figures on a blank page), then put back the front page and compile the document normally (as figures were already compiled, they are just included in the document).

Comment: I don't see how it comes from the snippet you show, but what I see is that you do some unfortunate things like naming several nodes `(a)`. I *suspect* that you have done some similar things in other pictures and then a combination of `overlay` and `remember picture` can cause this, but I am not sure. So my first advice is to name the nodes differently.

Comment: Your figure is wider than `\texwidth` in your MWE but we don't know your real document. Where is this blue line appearing? in final `pdf` in intermediate `dvi`? are you compiling with `pdflatex`, `latex`? do you use any `blue` line in other figures? ...

Comment: @marmot With the changed names of the nodes, the outcome is still the same.

Comment: @Ignasi The externalize command compiles an intermediate `pdf` that also has the blue line. I'm compiling with `PdfLaTeX`. I don't use anything with color and no blue lines appear in other figures.

Comment: Looks like something similar to this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/pgfplots-gives-spurious-lines-in-external-mode-with-geometry Probably your thesis layout uses some kind of blue lines, perhaps in the title page, which interfere with the shipout process done by the externalization mechanism.

Comment: @JLDiaz My thesis does not use any blue lines other than the front page. If it was this kind of issue shouldn't all figures demonstrate this behaviour?

Comment: @Syphirint It depends on the size of the figure. Externalization causes tikz to make the drawing in the upper left corner of an "empty" page, and then cropping the page to the size of the figure. My guess is that the "empty" page is not empty, but contains some kind of blue frame. If the figure is small enough, the cropped area would not include it. You may test the hypothesys by creating another figure as big as yours.

Comment: The hypotesis is correct. It draws the figure in the first page of the document and then crops it.

Comment: @Syphirint Then you may want to investigate how to draw your blue frame in a way with does not interfere with externalize. I don't know how you did it, but it probably has something to do with latex shipout mechanism. Perhaps you can change it for a tikz picture.

Comment: I meant avoiding the use of identical node names in all pictures. You might want to play around with `\tikzexternaldisable` and `\tikzexternalenable` (see section 50.4.3 of the pgfmanual) either around the frame or the above picture code.

Comment: Can you optimise away whatever commands draw the frame? Then they won't be executed when doing the externalisation.

Comment: I will try to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- for sure this image is not a cause for showed blue line
- for fun and exercise i re-code your mwe to

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadows, shapes}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{First Chapter}
 \section{First Section}
\lipsum[11]
 \begin{figure}[ht]
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
            > = latex,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick,
                 minimum size=16mm, align=center,
                 outer sep=0pt},
 block/.style = {box, draw, thick, minimum size=8mm},
 quant/.style = {box,
                 append after command={
        \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \draw[very thick]
        ($(\LN.south west)+(2mm,2mm)$) -| ++ (3mm,3mm) -| ++ (3mm,3mm)
                                       -| ++ (3mm,3mm) -- ++ (3mm,0mm);
                    }% end \pgfextra
                            }% end after command
                },
   sat/.style = {box,
                 append after command={
        \pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
        \draw[-Straight Barb]
        ($(\LN.south west)+(1mm,2mm)$) coordinate (a)
                                       edge  ($(\LN.south east)+(-1mm, 2mm)$)
        ($(\LN.south west)+(2mm,1mm)$)  to   ($(\LN.north west)+( 2mm,-1mm)$);
        \draw[very thick]
        ($(\LN.west)+(2mm,0mm)$) -- (\LN.west -| \LN.south)
                                 -- ([xshift=3mm] a -| \LN.south)
                                      node[above right,inner sep=1pt] {f};
                    }% end \pgfextra
                            }% end after command
                },
%every label/.append style = {font=\small}
                    ]
%
         \node (n1) [sat,label={[anchor=north] AAF}]    {};
         \node (n2) [block,right=of n1]                 {S/H};
         \node (n3) [quant,right=of n2,
                     label={[anchor=north]Quantizer}]   {};
         \node (n4) [block,right=of n3]                 {Binary\\ encoder};
%
    \draw[-Stealth] ($(n1.west)-(1,0)$) edge ["$x(t)$"]     (n1)
                    (n1)                edge ["$x_1(t)$"]   (n2)
                    (n2)                edge ["$y(k)$"]     (n3)
                    (n3)                edge ["$y(k)$"]     (n4)
                    (n4)                 to  ["$z$"]        ($(n4.east)+(1,0)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
     \caption{Generic scheme for an ADC.}
     \label{fig:generic_adc_scheme}
 \end{figure}
 \lipsum[12]
 \end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

- defined symbols in my mwe might be usefull in your other `tikz` pictures
- from discusion in comments below your question follows, that source of your  problem is externalization of `tikzpicture`
- one among possible solution is not use `externalization` but draw each image as separated document using `standalone` package for document class. for example as:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=0pt]{memoir}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shadows, shapes}

 \begin{document}
 ... image code ...
 \end{document}
```

and than obtained `pdf` file use as image:

```
 \begin{figure}[htb]
 \includegraphics{<file name>}
 \end{figure}
```

... just my 2 cents :-)

Comment: That should probably use the standalone class in the last mwe....

Comment: Due to my laziness I was trying to get a one click solution, but unfortunatly there are always drawbacks.

Comment: +1 Thanks! I haven't seen `\tikzlastnode` before. Will have to devel into section 17.14 of the manual:)

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, found that one could impose a white background in the figure, rendering **almost** everything in the first page "invisible" as follows:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=white}, show background rectangle]
        \node[anchor=south west] (x) at (0,0) {$x(t)$};

        \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (0,0)--(1,0);

        \draw  (1,-1) rectangle (3.5,1);
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.25mm]}] (1.2,-0.9)--(1.2,0.9);
        \draw[-{Latex[length=2.5mm, width=1.25mm]}] (1.1,-0.8)--(3.4,-0.8);
        \draw (1.2,0.2) -- (2.2,0.2);
        \draw (2.2,0.2) -- (3,-0.8);
        \node[anchor=center] (a) at (2.25,0.7) {AAF};
        \node[anchor=south east] (b) at (3.4,-0.8) {$f$};

        \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (3.5,0)--(5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$x_1(t)$};

        \draw  (5,-0.5) rectangle (6,0.5);
        \draw (5.5, -0.8) circle (0.1) node[anchor=north west] {$f_s$};
        \draw (5.5,-0.7) -- (5.5,-0.5);
        \node[anchor=center] (c) at (5.5,0) {S/H};

        \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (6,0)--(7.5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$y(k)$};

        \draw  (7.5,-1) rectangle (10,1);
        \draw (7.75,-0.9) -| (8.25,-0.5);
        \draw (8.25,-0.5) -| (8.75,0);
        \draw (8.75,0) -| (9.25,0.5);
        \draw (9.25,0.5) -- (9.75,0.5);
        \node[anchor=center] (d) at (8.75,0.75) {Quantizer};

        \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (10,0)--(11.5,0) node[anchor=south east] {$y(k)$};

        \draw  (11.5,-0.5) rectangle (13,0.5);
        \node[anchor=center] (e) at (12.25,0.2) {Binary};
        \node[anchor=center] (f) at (12.25,-0.2) {Encoder};

        \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}] (13,0)--(14,0) node[anchor=south east] {$z$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Generic scheme for an ADC.}
    \label{fig:generic_adc_scheme}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It is to notice that I wrote `almost everything`, as if there is text on top of the first page and the figure is large enough, the text will be shown.

Zerko's answer is a better solution I think, because it also leaves a better looking and less crowded main `.tex`.